# Manually-passed Angular route variable gets undefined in component

Tags: angular, url, parameters, routes, components

In my Angular component, I'm trying to get a variable that I manually pass from the route. I followed this tutorial: https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/angular2-retrieve-data-property-from-angular2-routes/. First, in my routing file, I added a data property to my route object, in which I define what I want to pass:

```
{
    path: ':id/dashboard/:sectionIndex',
    component: CampaignDashboardComponent,
    data: {
        section: 'dashboard' // this is what I need to retrieve in the component
    }
},
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'campaign-menu',
    templateUrl: './campaignMenu.component.html',
})
export class CampaignMenu implements OnInit {

    public sectionKey: string;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events
            .filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe(() => {
                var root = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root;
                while (root) {
                    if (root.children && root.children.length) {
                        root = root.children[0];
                    } else if (root.data && root.data["section"]) {
                        this.sectionKey = root.data["section"];
                        alert(this.sectionKey);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

In order to make this work, I have to manually change the route in the address bar of my browser. If I simply reload the page, the `sectionKey` variable doesn't get defined. When I do manually change the route, the variable gets defined, and I see it in the alert. However, the variable immediately gets undefined again, which I prove by trying to display the variable in the template. Do you have any idea why might cause this variable to get undefined?

Comment: What do you mean by manually changing the route? And what is that route, you change to? And when you reload again, what is the url that is shown?

Comment: I have to manually change the route in the address bar of my browser. E.g. change `/campaigns/1/dasbhoard` to `/campaigns/2/dashboard`. The URL stays the same if I reload. Anyway, I'm realizing now that when I reload a page, it's not working well with Angular's router. If, on the other hand, I click between links, using Angular's router, then the variable stays defined. So I'm guessing I need to force my page to use Angular's router upon page load, if that makes sense ...

Comment: Both `reload` and `click between the links` will be handled by angular's router. I don't understand how is that an issue.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Maybe I'm not describing it properly. All I know is that it doesn't work when I reload with the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is how you're attempting to access  the Route data in your controller. Instead of using `Router`, you should be using `ActivatedRoute` and then you have your choice of either subscribing to `.data` (if you need to react to changes after route load), or just accessing it directly via `.snapshot.data.data_property`. E.g.:

First, inject ActivatedRoute into your Controller:

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ...
)
```

Then, the 2 ways you can access it:

**Snapshot**

```
let dataVal = this.route.snapshot.data.data_property;
```

**Subscribe to Route Data**

```
this.route.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
    let dataVal = data.data_property;
});
```

Comment: This solved it. So much easier than my solution. Thanks!